# Using TensorFlow with GPU taking a long time for loading library related to CUDA

Tags: tensorflow, gpu

**Machine Setting:**

- GPU: GeForce RTX 3060
- Driver Version: 460.73.01
- CUDA Driver Veresion: 11.2
- Tensorflow: tensorflow-gpu 1.14.0
- CUDA Runtime Version: 10.0
- cudnn:  7.4.1

*Note:*

1. *CUDA Runtime and cudnn version fits the guide from Tensorflow official documentation.*
2. *I've also tried for TensorFlow-gpu = 2.0, still the same problem.*

**Problem:**

I am using Tensorflow for an objection detection task. My situation is that the program will stuck at

`2021-06-05 12:16:54.099778: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:42] Successfully opened dynamic library libcublas.so.10`

for several minutes.

And then stuck at next loading process

`2021-06-05 12:21:22.212818: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:42] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudnn.so.7`

for even longer time. You may check [log.txt](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensor2tensor/files/6602027/log.txt) for log details.

After waiting for around 30 mins, the program will start to running and *WORK WELL*.

However, whenever program invoke `self.session.run(...)`, it will load the same two library related to cuda (*libcublas* and *libcudnn*) again, which is time-wasted and annoying.

I am confused that where the problem comes from and how to resolve it. Anyone could help?

[Discussion Issue on Github](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensor2tensor/issues/1643)

===================================

**Update**

After @talonmies 's help, the problem was resolved by resetting the environment with correct version matching among GPU, CUDA, cudnn and tensorflow. Now it works smoothly.

Comment: The version Tensorflow you have doesn't have any native binary support for your GPU. As a result, there is JIT recompilation of *everything* tensorflow delay loads. That isn't fast. Upgrade to a version of Tensorflow with native support for your GPU or live with it are your two options

Comment: @talonmies Thx a lot for your help. I've reset the environment with correct version matching among GPU, CUDA, cudnn and tensorflow. Now it works smoothly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, if there are any incompatibility between TF, CUDA and cuDNN version you can observed this behavior.

For `GeForce RTX 3060`, support starts from `CUDA 11.x`. Once you upgrade to `TF2.4` or `TF2.5` your issue will be resolved.

For the benefit of community providing tested built configuration

[image]

CUDA Support Matrix

[image]

Comment: Thx for help :)